# using the current type in typedef in cpp

Tags: c++, templates, types, typedef

I need a data type which will hold either a string or a vector of the current data type. Here is a `typedef` I've written for that:

```
typedef std::variant<std::vector<value>, std::string> value;
```

Apparently this isn't valid, as `value` is an undeclared identifier when executing this line. So I tried first declaring `value` as another type and then using it in the same type:

```
typedef int value;
typedef std::variant<std::vector<value>, std::string> value;
```

this didn't work either, because the types are different.

So knowing this, what is the proper way of using the current type in a `typedef`?

Comment: Give one of the `typedef`s a different name. You've called them both `value`

Comment: And how would it work? What does it mean to have a `std::vector<value>` where `value` is `std::vector<value>`? You are trying to get an infinite recursion of types.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen yes, i know this is a seemingly infinite recursion of types. I want to be able to store a vector of the current type in the current type

Comment: It's not possible for one typename to refer to 2 different types. Compiler would not be able to distinguish which one is which.

Comment: @AanchalSharma i don't think my question wasn't clear enough. I know what I want, and my answer below or molbdnilo's answer solved my problem. If someone else understood the problem, then that means the question was clear enough for people to understand. Please do try to understand that one might actually need something you haven't needed, before coming and judging their experience with the language.

Comment: No language I know allows this exact form of type level recursion: you can't have a type `t` to be exactly equal to type `F<t>`. However, if you introduce a "wrapper", type recursion can be possible, e.g. `struct t { F<t> x; };` could be legal if `F<t>` only involves pointers/refs to `t`. By comparison, even in Haskell `type T = F T` is illegal, but the "wrapped" `newtype T = Wrap (F T)` is legal. The latter makes `T` and `F T` different types but isomorphic ones, and often isomorphism is all you actually need.

Comment: @James In the answer that you have accepted, the user has clearly written that "he thinks" what you want meaning he is not 100% certain what you want. You(@james) may already know what you want but this doesn't mean that everybody else will also know what you mean unless you describe your problem accurately. By looking at your posted code in your question, we can infer how much(or little) C++ you actually know. Not everyone can guess and answer your problem based on that guess.

Comment: @AanchalSharma your comment isn't valid, as I literally described what I wanted clearly and accurately in the first sentence of my question: "I need a data type which will hold either a string or a vector of the current data type.", leaving no room for guesswork. Either way, this question has an answer now so I think we can stop discussing about the clarity of the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're asking for:

```
struct Type
{
    using Value = std::variant<std::vector<Type>, std::string>;
    Value v;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of this, I created a class with a getter and a setter method:

```
class value {
  std::vector<value> children;
  std::string val;

 public:
  int index;
  value(
      std::variant<std::vector<value>, std::string> v) {
    this->set_value(v);
  }

  void set_value(
      std::variant<std::vector<value>, std::string> v) {
    if (v.index() == 0) {
      children = std::get<std::vector<value>>(v);
      index = 0;
    } else {
      this->val = std::get<std::string>(v);
      index = 1;
    }
  }

  std::variant<std::vector<value>, std::string> get_value() {
    if (index == 0) {
      return children;
    } else {
      return this->val;
    }
  }
};
```